# label on radar amchart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I realized an amChart with the online generator.
This is the result:

[image]
https://live.amcharts.com/ODVhY/

As you can see, the label with the value is visible only on the red bulled.

How can I extend it to all 5 bullet?

#### My configuration

```
{
    "type": "radar",
    "categoryField": "areas",
    "colors": [
        "#64cbd5",
        "#7cdae3"
    ],
    "startDuration": 1,
    "startEffect": "easeOutSine",
    "addClassNames": true,
    "color": "#EEEEEE",
    "fontFamily": "Ubuntu",
    "fontSize": 12,
    "theme": "dark",
    "graphs": [
        {
            "balloonText": "[[value]] in [[category]]",
            "bullet": "round",
            "bulletAlpha": 0,
            "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
            "bulletSize": 17,
            "clustered": false,
            "columnWidth": 0,
            "connect": false,
            "cursorBulletAlpha": 0,
            "descriptionField": "score",
            "fillAlphas": 0.79,
            "fillColors": "#64CBD5",
            "gapPeriod": 2,
            "id": "AmGraph-1",
            "labelAnchor": "middle",
            "labelOffset": 10,
            "labelPosition": "bottom",
            "labelText": "[[score]]",
            "legendAlpha": 0,
            "lineAlpha": 1,
            "lineColor": "#64CBD5",
            "lineColorField": "color",
            "lineThickness": 0,
            "minDistance": 0,
            "negativeBase": 2,
            "showAllValueLabels": true,
            "stackable": false,
            "switchable": false,
            "title": "[[value]] in [[category]]",
            "topRadius": 0,
            "valueField": "score",
            "visibleInLegend": false
        }
    ],
    "guides": [],
    "valueAxes": [
        {
            "axisTitleOffset": 20,
            "gridType": "circles",
            "id": "ValueAxis-1",
            "minimum": 0,
            "axisAlpha": 1,
            "gridAlpha": 0.35,
            "labelOffset": 2,
            "labelsEnabled": false,
            "tickLength": 3
        }
    ],
    "allLabels": [],
    "balloon": {},
    "titles": [],
    "dataProvider": [
        {
            "score": 156.9,
            "areas": "MEM",
            "color": "#22BCA7"
        },
        {
            "score": 131.1,
            "areas": "AGI",
            "color": "#76C741"
        },
        {
            "score": 115.8,
            "areas": "ATN",
            "color": "#FC385A"
        },
        {
            "score": 109.9,
            "areas": "PRS",
            "color": "#AD78AC"
        },
        {
            "score": 108.3,
            "areas": "VSP",
            "color": "#FC683E"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It's a bug in amCharts library, apparently. It has been reported to development and will be fixed in the next release, which is due within couple of days. If you are using Live Editor or load libraries from amCharts CDN, no additional steps are necessary, it will be updated automatically.

Comment: @martynasma Thank you very much

Comment: Hey, it was quicker than I expected. The new version is out now: https://www.amcharts.com/download/

Comment: @martynasma Not yet on live editor, is it?

Comment: Should be up now. Editor is somewhat lagging behind in terms of deployment of new versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @martynasma said in the comments, it was a bug of amcharts.
It is now fixed in the latest version.